# How do they do this? animated drawer rotation possible?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do they do this? animated drawer rotation possible?

In the screenshots below, touching the 'Touch' circle at the bottom causes that circle to rotate around itself, and then 4 new navigation buttons come out that take me to other screens/activities in the app. I really want to have this in my app..

Is it a sliding drawer or some other strategy? BTW I am targeting android version 2.1

[image: Start]

[image: Middle]

[image: Next]

[image: Then]

[image: Theeen]

[image: End]

Comment: Asians :P, by the way it looks cool can you give me market link or name something that helps me to understand the logic, just looking to screenshot giving me hundreds of possibilities that i know will eventually fail :).

Comment: It's called The Stage in Google Play

Comment: This might help you: http://code.google.com/p/android-path-like-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if it's mainly a animation that rotates an image. Once the animation has finished, the buttons are activated.

```
ImageView discsAndButtons = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.discsAndButtons);

Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f);
anim.setDuration(600);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setAnimationListener(this);

discsAndButtons.setAnimation(anim);

...

void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
   ViewGroup buttonLayer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.buttonLayer);
   buttonLayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Visually, the buttons are part of the image. But the effective buttons are probably on a separate layer above the image and only made visible after the animation has finished (except for the *TOUCH* button).